# Mocking Observable to throw error in Jest

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs, observable, angular-jest

I am trying to mock the `PUT` call of `HttpClient` of Angular to throw error. I am using `throwError` for it. It isn't working. What should I change to make it throw the error and call the `handleError` method? **I am using Jest**.

```
it(`should call the 'handleError' method when a request to store data was not successful`, () => {
    const error: HttpErrorResponse = {
      status: 401,
      message: 'You are not logged in',
    } as HttpErrorResponse;

    jest.spyOn(httpClientServiceMock, 'put').mockReturnValue(throwError(error));
    const spy = jest.spyOn(httpService, 'handleError');

    httpService.requestCall('some-url', ApiMethod.PUT, {});
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
  });
```

**service file**

```
  requestCall(url: string, method: ApiMethod, data?: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.xsrfToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    };

    const requestConfig = {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers,
    };

    switch (method) {
      case ApiMethod.GET:
        return this._http.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
      case ApiMethod.PUT:
        return this._http
          .put(url, data, requestConfig)
          .pipe(catchError((error) => this.handleError(error)));
    }
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): any {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error(`An error occurred: ${error.error.message}`);
    }

    return throwError({ error: error.message, status: error.status });
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You were pretty close!

You have to [subscribe to observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) returned from `httpService.requestCall('some-url', ApiMethod.PUT, {})` function. [There are additional changes required as this is asynchronous](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)

```js
const { of , throwError, operators: {
    catchError
  }
} = rxjs;

const httpClientServiceMock = {
  put: () => of ({
    value: 'test'
  })
};

const httpService = {
  requestCall(url, data, requestConfig) {

    return httpClientServiceMock
      .put(url, data, requestConfig)
      .pipe(catchError((error) => this.handleError(error)));
  },
  handleError(error) {
    return throwError({});
  }
};
const ApiMethod = {
  PUT: ''
}



const {
  expect,
  test,
  run,
  it,
  describe,
  jest
} = jestLite.core;

describe('httpService', () => {

  it(`should call the 'handleError' method when a request to store data was not successful`, done => {
    const error = {
      status: 401,
      message: 'You are not logged in',
    }

    jest.spyOn(httpClientServiceMock, 'put').mockReturnValue(throwError(error));
    const spy = jest.spyOn(httpService, 'handleError');

    httpService
      .requestCall('some-url', ApiMethod.PUT, {})
      .subscribe(pr => {
        done.fail(new Error(`It shouldn't go this path!`))
      }, error => {
        expect(spy).toBeCalled();
        done();
      });

  });

});

run().then(result => {
  console.log(result[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jest-lite@1.0.0-alpha.4/dist/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the reason why `done` should be avoided where possible because it creates many points of failure. `expect(spy).toBeCalled(); done();` - assertion fails, done is never called and results in a timeout, a dev is puzzled. Better use `async` and `toPromise` for RxJS testing, at least for completed observables.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the other answer, you have to subscribe to the returned observable.

I just wanted to add another approach which uses **marble-testing**, so you don't have to manually subscribe to that observable:

```js
let testScheduler;

beforeEach(() => testScheduler = new TestScheduler(assertionFn))

it(`should call the 'handleError' method when a request to store data was not successful`, () => {
  const error = {
    status: 401,
    message: 'You are not logged in',
  } as HttpErrorResponse;

  jest.spyOn(httpClientServiceMock, 'put').mockReturnValue(throwError(error));
  const spy = jest.spyOn(httpService, 'handleError');

  testScheduler.run(({ cold, expectObservable }) => {
    const src$ = httpService.requestCall('some-url', ApiMethod.PUT, {});
    
    expectObservable(src$).toBe('#', null, { error: error.message, status: error.status });
    expect(spy).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

`TestScheduler` is available in `rxjs/testing` and the `run`'s callback provides several helpers, such as: `cold`, `hot`, `flush`, `expectObservable`, `expectSubscriptions` and `time`.

What I personally like about this is that everything is synchronous, so you might not have to call `done()` when following such approach.

Comment: What is `assertionFn` in this snippet?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper It is a function that must comply with [this signature](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/packages/rxjs/src/internal/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L72). [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/packages/rxjs/spec/operators/filter-spec.ts#L12) is an example of how it could look like when testing the `filter` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`throwError('Message')` is deprecated instead use `throwError(callback)`

example:

```
     jest.spyOn(serviceClass,'serviceMethodName').mockReturnValueOnce(throwError(()=> {new Error('FAIL')}))
```